# Refresh view after UIBarButtonItem is clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a refresh button on my navigationbar

```
buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(buttonItemClicked)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
-(void)buttonItemClicked{
    NSLog(@"buttonItemclicked");
    myView.labelName.text = nil;
    myView.otherLabelName.text = nil;
    [spinner startAnimating]
    [spinnerView setHidden:NO];
    [self requestAPI];
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [spinnerView setHidden:YES];
  }
```

If I go in and out of the view, it works fine. But when I call the same methods in buttonItemClicked, it doesn´t work. I also tried calling the view methods inside my action method, but that doesn´t work either.

What I´m trying to do is set my labels to nil, add my `UIActivityIndicatorView` and remove it after the labels are set again.

I have already tried [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

The refresh it self works, but the animations doesn´t work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation is not working because you call startAnimating and stopAnimating (and setHidden) in the same method.
The render start at the end of the method call.
You need to set

```
[spinner stopAnimating];
[spinnerView setHidden:YES];
```

in `requestAPI`.

**Edit:**

Using Grand Central Dispatch. Like:

```
- (void)buttonItemClicked {
  myView.labelName.text = nil;
  myView.otherLabelName.text = nil;
  [spinner startAnimating]
  [spinnerView setHidden:NO];
  [self requestAPI];
}

- (void)requestAPI {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *stringResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [spinner stopAnimating];
      [spinnerView setHidden:YES];

      myView.labelName.text = stringResult;
    });

  });
}
```

Comment: @Sinetris If set my labels to nil and start the animation, in my action method it works fine, the animations that is. If I call requestAPI, the animations dones´t work. Have no idea what might be causing this.

Comment: @Magnus What requestAPI do? If you fetch data from the web (or your method run for few seconds) you need another thread (take a look at Grand Central Dispatch for "simplified" thread and ASIHTTPRequest for async web call).

Comment: I fetch data from a web service and putting the response I get in UILabels. But I can´t quite understand why it works in my view methods, and not in my action method for the UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: @Sinetris I tried to start a new thread in my action method, and it works fine. Only thing is I get lots of stuff in the console saying: __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xaa23f20 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking. Any idea how I can take care of this?

Comment: @Magnus Added an example using GCD (need iOS >= 4.0)

Comment: @Sinetris you´re an angel my friend :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try `[myView setsNeedToDisplay];`.